# R: 'Invalid subscript type symbol'

Tags: r, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation

I am currently working my way through the topics on expressions and quasiquotation in the [2nd edition of Hadley's Advanced R book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html). In the exercise section 20.6.5 the task is to

> "Implement arrange_desc(), a variant of `dplyr::arrange()` that sorts in descending order by default."

When playing around I noticed some things that puzzle me. First, I simply tried to write a function that will take a data frame and variables by which to order as an input. I wanted to automatically quote the variables to mirror `dplyr::arrange()`'s behaviour

```
arrange_desc2 <- function(.data, ...) {
   my_args <- enexprs(...)
   new_order <- order(.data[[my_args[[1]]]])
   return(list(my_args = my_args, new_order = new_order))
}

df <- data.frame(a = c(4, 3, 2, 1), 
                 b = c('d', 'c', 'b', 'a'))

arrange_desc2(df, a)

# $my_args
# $my_args[[1]]
# a

# $new_order
# [1] 4 3 2 1
```

This works, but frankly, I do not understand why: after all, I am subsetting with a symbol here. Digging deeper, I noticed that if I write the code like this, I get an error:

```
arrange_desc3 <- function(.data, ...) {
   my_args <- enexprs(...)
   new_order <- order(.data[, my_args[[1]]])
   return(list(my_args = my_args, new_order = new_order))
}

arrange_desc3(df, a)
# Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'symbol'
```

Why can I subset a list with a symbol (is it the same as an expression here?) and why is the symbol apparently evaluated using the list as an environment but only when using `[[`, not when using `[`? Put differently, what is the difference between:

```
a <- c(1, 1, 4, 3)
a[a]
# [1] 1 1 3 4
a[sym("a")] # but list(a = a)[[sym("a")]] will work!
# Error in a[sym("a")] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are converting to `symbol`, then `eval`uate it

```
a[eval(as.symbol("a"))]
#[1] 1 1 3 4
```

Or the same with `sym` from `rlang`

```
a[eval(rlang::sym("a"))]
#[1] 1 1 3 4
```

---

Regarding why the changed code didn't work, `order` is applied on `vector` or columns, By using `drop = FALSE`, it is a `data.frame`

Comment: But the error message already appears at the subsetting step of the data frame. Besides, I added drop = TRUE to the argument, which in combination with `[` turns it into a vector, just like `[[` as only one column is selected in either case. And I still do not get why subsetting a list with a symbol works but subsetting a vector with a symbol does not.

Comment: Sorry, just remembered that `drop = TRUE` is the default, I edited my post accordingly, the difference between `[` and `[[` still persists.